# Vanishing of the derivative of the tautological form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, principal-bundles

Let's consider the frame bundle $\text{Fr}(\mathbb{R}^n) = \mathbb{R}^n \times \text{GL}_n$ with bundle projection $\pi : \text{Fr}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and tautological $1$-form $\theta \in \Omega^1(\text{Fr}(\mathbb{R}^n), \mathbb{R}^n)$ given in this trivialization by

$$\theta_{(x, g)}(A, B) = g^{-1} A$$

Consider, for a point $p \in \text{Fr}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, a horizontal subspace $H_p \subset T_p \text{Fr}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, that is, one for which $d_p \pi|_{H_p} : H_p \to T_{\pi(p)} \mathbb{R}^n$ is an isomorphism, such that $(d\theta)|_{H_p} = 0$ (that is, $d\theta$ is always zero when calculated at two vectors from $H_p$). I've been trying to show that in this case necessarily we'd have $H_p = \mathbb{R}^n \oplus 0$, but I can't seem to do it. (I expect this to be true by some general considerations but I might be mistaken). Can anyone see how to do it?

It's probably helpful to note that $\iota_{\widetilde{X}} d\theta = - X \cdot \theta$, where $\iota$ is contraction and $\widetilde{X}$ is the infinitesimal generator of some $X \in \text{gl}_n$ (this follows essentially from Cartan's magic formula).

Comment: Is it not the case that since $d\pi_p$ gives an isomorphism from $H_p$ to $T_{\pi(p)}\mathbf{R}^n\cong\mathbf{R}^n$, we immediately have $H_p\cong\mathbf{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking if $H_p$ *equals* $\mathbb{R}^n \oplus 0$ (note that the tangent space of $\text{Fr}(\mathbb{R^n})$ at $p =(x, g)$ gets identified with $T_x \mathbb{R}^n \oplus T_g \text{GL}_n$).

Comment: So the question is if $H_p$ can have a vector with non-trivial vertical component, in a more invariant language.

Comment: It's unusual that you're trying to use the canonical 1-form rather than the Maurer-Cartan form of $GL_n$. But you have the structure equation $$d\theta = \pm\omega\wedge\theta,$$ where $\omega$ is the Maurer-Cartan form on $GL_n$. So what you're looking for follows directly from that.